What is the difference between set_process and flag management?
I have experience in smartphone app development, and I’ve always avoided using flag management for asynchronous programming, including things like semaphores, due to the risk of deadlocks. Instead, I’ve focused on using approaches like Grand Central Dispatch.
I'm not familiar with game programming, where methods like _process are called every frame. The ability to stop processing at any given moment using set_process(false) seems attractive to me.
However, set_process(false) feels like simple flag management. Isn’t there a risk of issues like deadlocks? Over time, alternative approaches like Grand Central Dispatch, Rx, Promise, and async/await have emerged, but is flag management still the mainstream in game development? (I understand that _process is just called every frame and not an asynchronous programming, so my experience with async programming might not directly apply.)
If set_process is essentially the same as flag management, then I plan to manage it using flags in game engines that don’t have an equivalent function. I would use a method similar to _process and implement early returns based on flags.

I would say that the difference is the set_process (event processing) system in Godot is well defined / documented. The term "flag management" is not.
